# Mysql services dies sometimes when you use wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, centos, mariadb

I'm using nginx 1.8.1 on centos 7 64 bit, i have installed wordpress there and it works great, but sometimes  when you install plugin, or do some other activity on the site mysql service dies and it shows **error establishing a database connection** error since the service just died and didn't started again.

So what i did several times when this happened (I'm holding the site on the server ~3 days issue started coming day ago when there where more plugins on the site or more activity i'm not sure whats causing the issue) is connected to the server via putty client and just wrote **reboot** command that solved the issue, however couple hours ago when the issue randomly just popped up when i was adding simple products on Woocommerce i logged in to server via putty and now just wrote **systemctl stop mariadb** and than **systemctl start mariadb**. I tough mysql server just dies randomly, but after 15 minutes it happened again so now i didn't wrote  command to stop maria db i just wrote **systemctl start mariadb** and it didn't worked, what it says is:

```
[root@lrweb ~]# systemctl start mariadb
Job for mariadb.service failed. See 'systemctl status mariadb.service' and 'journalctl -xn' for details.
```

So next thing i did is wrote command to check status( **systemctl status mariadb**
 ): and it shows:

```
[root@lrweb ~]# systemctl status mariadb
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2016-02-09 03:48:11 EST; 45s ago
  Process: 24708 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 24707 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 24680 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 24707 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
```

So now i decided to stop maria db and start again like i did before but once i type command to stop maria db it outputs nothing just

```
[root@lrweb ~]# systemctl stop mariadb
[root@lrweb ~]#
```

But when i type again for start the service it does not start and gives me same 
message as i wrote above.

I'm sure that i can resolve this issue by rebooting the server which would start services all automatically.

I'm using digital ocean in in there i decided to go and check resources, i have there server which is medium one and it can't be that high but apparently i was wrong because it shows that all resources was at max:

[Click to see resource graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ge1v.png)

I'm not sure whats causing the problem, how to fix it and what i do wrong.

Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: Can you run this command: `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables` and paste the output?

Comment: I should run this command when the problem is active or when everything is ok?

Comment: Is just for testing if mariadb can run on safe mode...that way you can make a backup of you wordpress database and try then another solution to your problem, like, purge and reinstall mariadb

Comment: Ahh, by the way i followed this youtube tutorial to prepare my server https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=C_6jxrCA1P8 in addition i increase post_max size and max_upload_size also installed soap client

Comment: What's in `mysqld.err`?

Comment: I have resolved my problem, increased ram up to 4gb. Turns out before service goes offline it says that it failed allocate some memory. if i would not use such company like digitalocean i would say that it's a scam by hosting company. 2gb ram not enough hold 1 wordpress site with simple theme and couple of plugins on centos that all i had, back in the days i used to host 5 my sites on 1gb ram. Well hopefully this is fixed, didn't saw whole day any error since i increased memory.